# enviar id por get en laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy comanzando con Laravel y debo enviar el codigo de un reporte en especifico a el controlador para poder filtrar e imprimir el pdf.

este es el listado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el boton de pef tiene la siguiente codificacion

```
 <button class='btn btn-primary' value='imprimir pdf'
   onclick ="window.location.href='{{ Route('pdf.index',$result->cod_reporte) }}'">
   <i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>
 </button>
```

alli me envia el codigo del reporte al controlador pero no se como puedo almacenarlo en una variable en la funcion index para poder filtrar con este al momento de hacer la consulta en la base de datos

este es el codigo de el controlador, funcion index:

```
public function index()
{
    $data= DB::table('reportes')
        ->join('usuarios','reportes.id_us','=','usuarios.id_us')->limit(1)
        ->join('estatus','reportes.id_estatu',"=",'estatus.id_estatu')
        //->where('cod_report', '=', $id )
        ->select('cod_reporte','fecha_crea','usuarios.nombre','usuarios.apellido','usuarios.telefono','usuarios.correo')
        ->get();
        dd($data);   

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.reportinsidencia',['data' => $data]);
    return $pdf->stream('reportinsidencias.pdf');
}
```

y en el archivo web la ruta es la siguiente

```
Route::get('/Report/pdf',[PdfController::class, 'index'])->name('pdf.index');
```

Comment: si, eso es lo que necesito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define tu ruta con el parametro requierido.

   - En tu ruta tienes que definir el parametro que vas a enviar por url, en tu caso: `result->code_reporte`

   `Route::get('/Report/{code_reporte}/pdf',[PdfController::class, 'index'])->name('pdf.index');`
2. Agrega el parámetro que recibirás en tu función.

   ```
   public function index($cod_reporte)
   { 
     $data= DB::table('reportes')
       ->join('usuarios','reportes.id_us','=','usuarios.id_us')->limit(1)
       ->join('estatus','reportes.id_estatu',"=",'estatus.id_estatu')
       ->where('cod_report', '=', $cod_reporte ) //uso de variable
       ->select('cod_reporte','fecha_crea','usuarios.nombre','usuarios.apellido','usuarios.telefono','usuarios.correo')
       ->get();
   }
   ```

   Ya dentro de tu funcion index podras utilizar la varaiable `$cod_reporte`

Te sugiero dar una leída a la documentación:
[Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters)